# HTML - input value kept after Refresh

Tags: html, input, refresh

Usually, when a refresh is made on an HTML page, the values for input fields are kept (unless you do Ctrl+F5).

Is there a header or other type of setting than can change this behavior, without chaging anything on the form or input itself?

I have a site where the input value is not kept after a page refresh in Production. However I do not have this behavior when I test this code on my local machine.

Comment: Are you trying to add this behaviour to one of your pages, or trying to figure out how the site you mentioned does it so that you can disable the behaviour?

Comment: Indeed, it seems most people who answered did not get it.
I'm trying to understand how the site I'm checking does it, it order to change this behavior. I'm updating my question to be clearer.

Comment: This is a Firefox only issue. See the following "discussion" for a 10 year history on this one item: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46845  I find comment #123 to be the most telling

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17803187/1599699

Answer (score 79):

If you set the attribute `autocomplete=off`, the content will never be stored.

Alternatively, there's a plethora of ways to accomplish this with javascript, depending on exactly what you want to accomplish, whether it be clearing the whole form (use the reset() method), or resetting the single field.

Comment: This wasn't accepted cause the question asked for no changes on the inputs. What makes no much sense to me. @sonnb

Comment: Where do you set this attribute? On the form or on the input? Somewhere else?

Comment: "...there's a plethora of ways to accomplish this..." Oh well gee thanks for telling them to us

Answer (score 10):

You can add form.reset() to the body onload:

```
<html>
    <body onload="form1.reset();">
        <form id="form1">
            <textarea id="text"></textarea>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Update: while this might be a useful technique, I have now found out that it doesn't actually answer the submitter's question.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no standard way to implement it, so before you can disable it, you first you need to determine how the site is doing it. There are many ways they could have done it, as you can see from the variety of different answers here.

A good way of understanding what is going on is to reduce the code to the simplest possible example that still reproduces the issue. Remove all graphics, unneeded text, style sheets and other formatting, irrelevant javascript, irrelevant HTML tags, etc. but always checking that you can still reproduce the issue. Eventually there will be so little code left that it should be obvious what it is that is causing the fields to be reset. You will have to do all this on the production machine, since you cannot reproduce it locally. To do this, take a copy of the scripts and rename them to index2.html, etc. Make sure you have backups of your production system before doing this, in case something goes wrong.

If you still can't understand how to fix the issue after doing this, the code should be sufficiently small that it can be posted here and someone else will be able to work it out.

Answer (score 2):

How about setting a default value on DOM ready with JavaScript?

Something like

```
<input name="foo" id="foo" type="text">

$('#foo').val('3')
```

Comment: document.getElementById('foo').value = 3 for those who aren't using jquery.

Comment: It's just an example. You can use anything you want instead of '3'.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use this:

```
var reset_input_values = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (var i = 0; i < reset_input_values.length; i++) {
  reset_input_values[i].value = 'value you want ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this solved.

Work Around:

1. Add a boolean flag to your typescript file and set disable(false) by default
2. Place `*ngIf` on your html
3. On `ngAfterViewInit()` set that to `true`

Comment: This is assuming OP is using angular