# How to clear history of text input

Tags: html, browser

On my HTML page I have multiple text inputs. Every time I enter values in them, it shows me the previously entered values. Is it due to a browser property or HTML? How do I disable it?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Always the better appraoch is to give **form** autocomplete="off"

```
<form autocomplete="off">

<input type="text" id="text1">
<input type="text" id="text2">

</form>
```

Then only newer versions of Eclipse support HTML5 tags such as autocomplete else it will show warning...

Answer (score 29):

Just set the `autocomplete` property of your textboxes to off. Like this...

```
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: i tried that, it says "Undefined attribute name (autocomplete)"

Comment: which browser are you using ?

Comment: chrome/firefox/ie testing on all of them as I want it to work on all known bowers

Comment: well it is working, eclipse says "Undefined attribute name (autocomplete)" but it is working anyways, strange!

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe to clear things up, are you getting this "Undefined attribute name (autocomplete)" in your browser or developement environment? Because googling such error directs me to eclipse problems.

Comment: @Puuskis yes i was getting it in eclipse in fact i am still getting it but it is working in browser.

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe Yeah my bad, answered the same moment I guess :) There seems to be workarounds for such problems. Not too familiar with the eclipse, but worth a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193905/warnings-of-valid-html5-attributes-in-eclipse (just because it's annoying to see warnings)

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe is this thing working... i dont think so..??y u have marked as answer?

Comment: @ArunBertil it is working, the problem is in eclipse, showing warning to a valid attribute.

Comment: Ohh that is beacuse only newer versions of Eclipse support HTML5 tags   allowed in HTML5....you can either add html5 tags add on..

Answer (score 4):

That solution helped me:
if you are using google Chrome, try this:
Put the mouse pointer on the entry that you want to delete,
press <kbd>Delete</kbd>.
If the entry is not removed, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

i think it is related to this question [autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form)

try to used javascript to add attribute autocomplete to your form

```
someForm.setAttribute( "autocomplete", "off" ); someFormElm.setAttribute( "autocomplete", "off" );
```

Answer (score -1):

just try this lines below

```
$('input').each(function(k,v){
   $(v).val(''); 
});
```

works fine with me