# Explicitly clear form field even though value=" " has been given

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am displaying data from my database in an HTML form to make it editable by the user.

```
<input type="text"  id="name" placeholder="Name" required = " true"  value = <?php if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) echo $_SESSION['name'] ;?>>
```

There is a reason why I had to use session storage. The problem here is, when I refresh the page, it displays the old value stored in the session. Is there a way to explicitly clear the form while its loaded? I tried JavaScript and jQuery reset(), that doesn't work as its not a user input tht can be cleared.
Edit. This is not a case dealing with auto complete, to be more precise , I have another form to read an unique id which I use to query from the data base . The database results are stored in the session storage and I'm echoing them to the 2nd form.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're asking. You are deliberately putting the session variable into the field when the page is loaded (without surrounding quotes btw), do you want the entered / changed value to remain when the page is refreshed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear history of text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802690/how-to-clear-history-of-text-input)

Comment: You will have to find a way to distinguish a "normal" page load from a reload. Look for localStorage. Then if it's a reload, `$("#name").val("");` will do in a document ready handler to clear the value. You could event force the "new" value from before the reload, with [**localStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: <form autocomplete="off">

Comment: @AmrBerag: the question isn't about autocomplete at all!

Comment: I am display a value that I have retrieved from the database, the user can make changes and the updated value is put into the database.

Answer (score 1):

`reset` will just restore the elements to the state the markup dictates, which won't help.

Instead, you need to set the `defaultValue` of the elements to the new default, and then use `reset` (or just assign to `value` at the same time). `defaultValue` is the property that reflects the `value` attribute.

Example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Clearing defaultValue and resetting...");
  $("#the-form input").prop("defaultValue", "");
  $("#the-form")[0].reset();
}, 800);
```

```html
<form id="the-form">
<input type="text"  id="name" placeholder="Name" required = " true"  value = "value from markup">
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To figure out whether you need to do that, you might save the PHP session ID in client-side `sessionStorage` (along the lines of [Louys Patrice Bessette's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785640/explicitly-clear-form-field-even-though-value-has-been-given/50785679#comment88577819_50785640)) and only do this when they match. Along these lines on load:

```
var phpSessionId = <?php echo json_encode(session_id())?>;
if (sessionStorage.getItem("phpsessionid") != phpSessionId) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("phpsessionid", phpSessionId);
} else {
    // reset the fields -- perhaps even to values you stored in `sessionStorage`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be very simple. I destroyed the session after displaying in a jQuery on click function.

```
<?php session_destroy(); ?>
```